# Introduction to programming using SML exercise 1.3

Tags: math, recursion, functional-programming, sml

I am currently working through the Introduction to programming using SML book released back in 1999. I would like your help on how to declare a recursive function for exercise 1.3, which I have been stuck on for some time now.

1.3: Declare a recursive function f: int -> int, where
f(ᶯ) = 1 + 2 + ... + (ᶯ - 1) + ᶯ for ᶯ ≥ 0

Hint: Use two clauses with 0 and ᶯ as argument patterns. State the recursion formula corresponding to the declaration.

If anyone can provide some guidance on this that would be great.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: I have not written any code for this function yet because I am trying to understand what it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More literal hint:

The solution is supposed to look like this:

```
fun sum 0 = ... something ...
  | sum n = ... something else ...
```

You'll need to figure out

1. What is `sum 0`?
2. What information do you need in order to be able to calculate `sum n`?

If you're stuck, write down the calculation of `f(1)`, `f(2)`, `f(3)`, and `f(4)` on a piece of paper and see if you can spot a pattern.

Comment: I think this may have helped me. Here is what I have:

`fun f 0 = 0
    | f n = n + f(n-1);`